# What is the difference between RSE and squared mean(bias^2)?

Tags: regression, residuals, bias

\begin{align}
{\rm bias} &= E(f-\hat{f})^2  \\[7pt]
{\rm RSE} &= \sqrt{\frac{RSS}{n-p-1}}
\end{align}

where $RSS=e_1^2+e_2^2...$

Since the above formuala is right, what is the difference between bias and RSE? Are they not the same?

Comment: Please modify your question so that it is more readable along with more details.

Comment: I am new to cross validated. Sorry for the mistakes. I guess someone edited my question.